# Predicting user selections based on previous answers and datetime

Tags: regression, time-series, references, online-algorithms

I'm completely new to machine learning and wish to implement it into my app to help my users travel between places. Let's say I have data (constantly updating data) that looks like this:

```
user|from_id|to_id|timestamp
1234|4365|23075|xxx
```

Where from_id and to_id is the start/stop place's ID. Based on this I would want to predict and suggest to the user where to go in the future based on the timestamp (and possibly either from_id or to_id).

So for example; Let's say that I've been looking for routes to my work every weekday around 8 AM. I would then enter the user I'd want to predict and the current date/time into this algorithm and if the time is around 8 AM on a weekday it'd suggest a route from home to work because it's that time of the day.

I've been looking at the linear regression but I'm unsure if it can handle time series without a fixed time between each data, and also if linear regression is suitable for `online machine learning`? Are there any projects on ex. GitHub which could help me get started?